# Android fragment translation right to left

Tags: android, android-fragments, translation, slide

i want to have a translation right to left, when a fragment disappear to show another fragment.

I have this for my translation :

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.lefttoright,R.anim.righttoleft);
```

And my translation left & right :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="700"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

but it's not running, only translation left to right runs... why ?

Comment: ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.righttoleft,R.anim.lefttoright);

Comment: do u want the translation on the back pressd ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### slide1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="350"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

### slide2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="350"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

### Java Code

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide1, R.anim.slide2);
```

Comment: nop, it's doing the same thing, i've the same result.. it's sliding left to right.

Comment: App Crashing after animation :( NulLPointerException   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3197)

Answer (score 1):

In `anim` directory

**slide_left_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/default_transaction_animation_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**slide_left_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/default_transaction_animation_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**slide_right_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/default_transaction_animation_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**slide_right_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/default_transaction_animation_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

In `values` directory

**integers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="default_transaction_animation_duration">350</integer>
</resources>
```

In Java

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_right_in, R.anim.slide_left_out,
                R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_right_out);
```

[image]